# Where can specific files for an old Linux kernel (2.6.x) be found?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I need to find an *old* driver (kernel/drivers/hid/hid-picolcd.c) located into the old kernel 2.6.35.14.

But I cannot find the version on http://kernel.org

I need just this file, or just one file. Is it possible to navigate a chosen version of the Linux kernel?

Comment: This is completely off topic for SO

Comment: As much as I think this should be closed, the links in the answers below are quite interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This guy? http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.35.14/drivers/hid/hid-picolcd.c

Answer (score 1):

This website is pretty good for viewing linux source code:

http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.35.14/

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse you can browse through gitweb of all the different version of the kernel. The [file](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=blob_plain;f=drivers/hid/hid-picolcd.c;hb=HEAD) you are looking for is in the [kernel git repository for 2.6.35.14](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=summary)

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the version you'd like to see at

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/hid/hid-picolcd.c